# How would I have someone input code, full with tabs and lines, and keep that figure

Tags: php, parsing

I have a textarea that someone can put code in. When someone clicks "Submit" it will create a txt file, and then re-display it somewhere else. But since it's code, I really need to keep the tabs and lines exactly the same. Using PHP, how would I go about that?

Comment: If you don't ever `trim` the text, shouldn't it retain its tabs and whitespace?  Are you having problems with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you are dumping the code to a web page.  You might want to wrap the code dump in `<pre>...</pre>` tags.

Observe:

```
<pre>
<?php echo $code ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace them with `&nbsp;`:

```
$str = preg_replace('/ (?= )/', '&nbsp;');
$str = preg_replace('/\t/', '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
```

This will turn this:

```
I would like  to show   tabs and spaces

                      ^ this is a tab
```

into this:

```
I would like&nbsp; to show&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;tabs and spaces
```

which should display fine.